# How to reference a column name with blanks

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, content-type

Using workflow, I need to email all items in a list. I got the "Call WS" correctly. I can loop thru each item and reference a column "SolutionType". However, if I change this to "Solution Type" I cannot. I tried:

1. d/results([%Variable: index%])/Solution%5Fx0020%5FType
2. d/results([%Variable: index%])/Solution_x0020_Type
3. d/results([%Variable: index%])/'Solution Type'

I actually need to access the built-in columns "Task Name" and "Assigned To" but I want to practise on my own column first. Please tell the proper way. Thx!

Comment: _Object_**["Solution Type"]**

Comment: I tried. No errors, but the return values are empty.

Comment: Ah... you better add the word workflow, I thought you where doing JavaScript

Comment: By "column name with blanks" do you mean a column with spaces in its name?

Comment: Did you try it without the spaces? If the column was originally created without spaces then the internal name wouldn't have spaces and also wouldn't change when you changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
d/results([%Variable: index%])/matches(., "Solution\sType")
```

Comment: **Nope. That results following error: **Resume this workflow  
 RequestorId: f10fd288-61e2-1bf8-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: The DynamicValue property 'd/results(0)/matches(., 'Solution\sType')' was incorrectly formatted.

Comment: I've changed ' to "

Comment: Same issue: `Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: The DynamicValue property 'd/results(0)/matches(., "Solution\sType")' was incorrectly formatted`

Answer (score 0):

I got around the problem by create new columns "TaskName", "AssignedTo" and "SolutionType" calculated from appropriated columns whose names have space. *Not pretty!*

I solved the problem! The column name in sharepoint is very ambiguous. In Listing Settings -> Edit Column, whatever you type in "Column Name" is what seen on the listing, but not what you would reference in the code. Instead, look at the URL; whatever specified in Field=??? ... that's the real field name.

In example1, the column heading is "Solution Type" but in my code, I must refer to this field as "SolutionType"
 [image: example1]

In example2, the column heading is "Task Name" but in my code, I must refer to this field as "Title"
 [image: example2]

Lastly, if the field name originally created with blank in it, then of course one can use the "*x0020*" or "%5Fx0020%5F" for the blanks